# InternalServerError on hitting Django API from the Azure Function

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

[image]I am trying to send the mail informations to the django API from the azure function but the request fails stating - InternalServerError.

I am trying to use the python requests in the azure function to send request to django API

```py
import logging
import requests
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    req_body = req.get_json()

    To = req_body.get('To')
    From = req_body.get('From')
    Subject = req_body.get('Subject')
    Body = req_body.get('Body')
    Attachments = req_body.get('Attachments')

    email_df = [{
        "To" : To,
        "From" : From,
        "Subject" : Subject,
        "Body" : Body
    }]
    requests.post('https://lcms.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com//mail-save/', json = email_df)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{ To } { From } { Subject } { Body }!")
```

Comment: Hi Soumitra. May I know the request body you provided to the function in your logic app and could you please share some more details(screenshots) of your logic app ? (If you did some operation to the request body in the "For each" loop, please also share the screenshot of the details in "For each").

Comment: Actually I discovered the problem and it seems that azure function doesn't has the "requests" module I am trying to import. Can you please help me regarding that because I am unable to find any proper resource that would help me in installation of module over azure function

Comment: Hi Soumitra, may I know if the solution help you to import the "requests" module ?

Comment: @HuryShen Thank you so much it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you develop the function locally, you can create a "requirements.txt" and add the names and versions of the required packages to it. Then use the command below to install the package.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After that, publish the function to Azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish <app name> --build remote
```

For further information about these steps, please refer to this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#python-version-and-package-management